# Unable to Route a Page in RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having problem in writing a route here is what i wrote in the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^forums/139638-ideas/suggestions/([0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9-])?$ suggestion.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Example of route which it should render is :

```
forums/139638-ideas/suggestions/2489549-ability-to-print
```

where `2489549` is the id which i am sending and `-` is the separator and then the `ability-to-print` is the title of that page but i am unable to route to that page is there something wrong in my regex or am i writing the rule in a wrong manner. Sorry about my English and as well as i am new to Route writing so sorry for that as well if you think its a newbie question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have left out the `+` for the second segment, which indicates that multiple characters can be matched. This is the same as what you did for the first segment.

So, your rule should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^forums/139638-ideas/suggestions/([0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$ suggestion.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Notice the additional `+` in the second segment.

Comment: Thanks mate its working now but i am having another problem now i have 2 get parameters i want to send but i am unable to get the 2nd parameter here is the rule i wrote:

`RewriteRule ^knowledgebase/topics/([0-9]+)-(([A-Za-z0-9-]+))\?page=([0-9]+)?$ topic.php?id=$1&page=$4 [NC,L]`

the expexted URL is 

`knowledgebase/topics/6457-microsoft-office-application-information?page=2`

here `6457` is the first get that is `id` and then the title then `?page=` then the 2nd get paramter `2`

but unable to get that page variable

Comment: You should put this in a new question as it well help others with the same problem. But anyways, try this: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$` Next line: `RewriteRule ^knowledgebase/topics/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)$ topic.php?id=$1%1`. It basically passes the query string over onto the actual route as Rewrite Rules can't pick them up. See this article for more: http://zenverse.net/capture-query-string-get-data-in-htaccess-rewrite/

Comment: Thanks Mate ye put that in other question answer was similar :)